# Are selfsigned certificates and certificates with a wildcard character in CN blocked in Java by default?

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am building a JAX-WS client that connects to a server which uses selfsigned certificates with a wildcard character in the CN. The subject filed of the certificates looks like:

```
"CN=*.mylocation.mycompany.corp, O=MyCompany, C=MyCountry"
```

Because there are selfsigned certificates on the server side my JAX-WS client works only with am explicit trust manager that accepts all certificates. Such as one described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https?lq=1).

I keep coming across statements such as "Sun's JSSE doesn't support wildcard", for example in the answer to [Can Java connect to wildcard ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166373/can-java-connect-to-wildcard-ssl).

I cannot find any official documentation from oracle about self-signed/wildcard certificates certificates being blocked or to support the statements such as the one above.

Is this true? Is there any official documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two StackOverflow answers that hone in on your question:

1. [telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)
2. [How can I use different certificates on specific connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

Comment: Thanks, I've exactly done the same thing in my code as the answers in those questions. But all I am looking for is some kind of official documentation from oracle that says self-signed certificates and wildcard certificates are blocked by deault in Java

Comment: Regarding self-signed there is no need for official documentation: Java validates a certificate and a self-signed certificate can not be verified since there is no trusted issuer for this certificate in the key store. Thus self-signed certificates get not blocked but simply the validation fails. If you would import the certificate in the key store it should work.

Comment: Even if you import the certificate in keystore you still need to set an explicit trust manager programatically, that accepts all certificates. Am I right?

Comment: no, once you have imported the certificate into cacerts ( jre/lib/security/cacerts ) - you dont need to set up trust managers programatically, yet you have to set up CN property pointing to host (or add SAN extensions to allow host/ips) otherwise you gonna get hostname verification exceptions.